# O que significa incrementar?

Tags: terminologia

Gostaria de saber o que significa o termo *incrementar*, e em que situação devo utilizá-lo. Estou aprendendo lógica de programação e ouço falar muito nisso, mas não entendo exatamente o que significa.

Comment: Oi, bemvindo ao site :) Sugiro que você confira os guias [about], [ask] e [answer], pois parece que vc está começando com o pé esquerdo... Uma conferida geral na [help] também é importante.

Comment: Incrementar variáveis? Ex: x++; ou x += 1;

Comment: Por que os votos contrários? Certamente essa pergunta - na forma como está (pode ser editada e melhorada, se o OP quiser) - deve ser fechada como descontextualizada, mas não é o caso de votar contra... (P.S. No contexto de programação, "incrementar uma variável" é o mesmo que "somar `1` ao seu valor" - em geral guardando o resultado na própria variável em que foi aplicado o incremento. É isso que você está perguntando?)

Comment: Qual seria a tag mais apropriada para isso? Java é que não é.

Comment: Não considero essa pergunta como "ampla demais". A resposta aceita mostra bem isso.

Comment: Seria interessante se o AP marcasse a resposta que ele se identificou como solução para sua pergunta.

Answer (score 20):

Parece que você está começando a programar ou aprendendo lógica de programação, certo?

Quando eu passei por essa fase, ouvi bastante o termo *incrementar* estudando laços de repetição, onde em um laço **faça até** por exemplo, uma variável é *incrementada* ou *decrementada* até satisfazer uma determinada condição. Nesses casos:

**Incrementar**

Como o @mgibsonbr já comentou, é o mesmo que somar uma quantidade ao valor atual de uma variável, geralmente armazenando o resultado nela mesma (na variável).

```
x = 10;
x = (x + 5); //incrementar 5
```

Nesse exemplo x passa a valer 15, pois 10 + 5 = 15.

**Decrementar**

É muito parecido com incrementar, mas nesse caso subtrai-se um valor da variável ao invés de somar.

```
x = 10;
x = (x - 5); //decrementar 5
```

Nesse exemplo x passa a valer 5, pois 10 - 5 = 5.

Obs: Não se sinta envergonhado de perguntar coisas básicas, mesmo que suas perguntas recebam vários votos negativos, pois todo mundo passou por essa etapa para chegar onde estão hoje... Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Minha próxima pergunta será: *Por que é que quando eu declaro duas variáveis (X e Y) e inicializo elas com valores diferentes, quando o programa executa* `X = Y; Y = X;` *os valores delas não trocam?*

Answer (score 9):

Conforme o dicionário, INCREMENTAR é:

1. desenvolvimento
2. aumento
3. ato de crescer
4. ato de aumentar

Em programação o significado é o mesmo, iremos aumentar algo já existente. E também existe a opção de decrementar algo já existente, ou seja, diminuir/retirar.

**Operadores Incrementais e Decrementais**

Os operadores incrementais e decrementais tem a função de aumentar ou diminuir exatamente em 1 o valor de uma variável. Eles podem ser pré ou pós incremental e pré ou pós decremental. Veja os conceitos de cada um deles e um exemplo prático a seguir:

**- Incremental (++):**

·         Pré incremental ou prefixo – Significa que, se o sinal for colocado antes da variável, primeiramente será somado o valor 1 para esta variável, continuando em seguida a resolução da expressão.

```
$x = 0;
$resultado = ++$x + 20;
echo $resultado; // o valor de 21
```

·         Pós incremental ou sufixo – Significa que, se o sinal for colocado após a variável, é resolvido primeiro a expressão, seja ela adição, subtração, multiplicação ou qualquer outra, para em seguida ser adicionado o valor 1 à variável.

```
$x = 0;
$resultado = ($x++) + 20;
echo $resultado; // o valor de 20
echo $x // o valor é 1
```

**- Decremental (--):**

·         Pré incremental ou prefixo – Significa que, se o sinal for colocado antes da variável, primeiramente será subtraído o valor 1 para esta variável, continuando em seguida a resolução da expressão.

```
$x = 0;
$resultado = --$x + 20;
echo $resultado; // o valor de 19
```

·         Pós incremental ou sufixo – Significa que, se o sinal for colocado após a variável, é resolvido primeiro a expressão, seja ela adição, subtração, multiplicação ou qualquer outra, para em seguida ser subtraído o valor 1 à variável.

```
$x = 0;
$resultado = ($x--) + 20;
echo $resultado; // o valor de 20
echo $x // o valor é -1
```

Fonte: O que é [INCREMENTAR](http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/incremento)

Answer (score 8):

### Resposta curta

Incrementar é um termo comum na programação, que se refere a adicionar 1 a uma variável, e armazenar o valor na própria variável.

Seria o mesmo que fazer assim:

```
valor = valor + 1
```

### Porque existe um operador de incremento

Esse termo se tornou tão comum pelo fato de essa ser uma operação muito utilizada, possuindo até mesmo instruções específicas do processador destinadas à operação de incremento.

Ela é muito utilizada, principalmente em loops (exemplo em C#):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
}
```

Note que a operação de incremento será utilizada pelo menos 1000 vezes neste laço.

Acontece que o laço feito dessa forma é uma estrutura de código muito utilizada, e por isso requer performance máxima, de tal forma que o impacto do laço em si seja mínimo e afete pouco o código que realmente importa, que está dentro do laço.

Quase todas as linguagens possuem um operador de incremento. O C# é só um exemplo, mas o operador existe em várias outras linguagens: javascript, C, C++, java.

### O operador `++`

Nas linguagens que usam o operador `++`, geralmente a linguagem permite usar de duas formas.

- prefixo **`++valor`**: o valor a ser retornado por esta expressão é o valor após o incremento. Ou seja:

  ```
  valor = 10;
  valor2 = ++valor; // valor2 será atribuido com o valor 11
  ```
- sufixo **`valor++`**: o valor a ser retornado por esta expressão é o valor antes do incremento. Ou seja:

  ```
  valor = 10;
  valor2 = valor++; // valor2 será atribuido com o valor 10
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Incrementar = Somar

Incrementar 5 ao resultado > `resultado = resultado + 5`

Incrementar o resultado > `resultado = resultado + 1`

Answer (score 5):

Incrementar é o termo que define a ação de somar um novo valor a um existente. Na maior parte das linguagens por padrão o termo define a soma de um numero existente com 1.

**Exemplo em javascript:**

```
// A variavel test é definida com o valor 1.
var test = 1;

// A variável test é "incrementada" e passa a ter o valor 2.
// É o mesmo que:
// test = test + 1;
test++;
```

Também existe o termo decremento que é usado para definir a subtração ao envés da adição.

**Exemplo:**

```
test--;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. **Incrementar**

Em uma situação em que você está aprendendo a utilizar o laço de repetição `for`, incrementar um número vai ser relacionado a quantas vezes você vai operar uma soma *+1* nessa variável.

Exemplificando com um algoritmo bem simples, em que um usuário *"X"* decide o número que será incrementado, e quantas vezes o mesmo será incrementado:

```c
int main(){
    
    int A; /* A vai ser o número que será incrementado */
    int B; /* B vai ser quantas vezes esse número que será incrementado */
    
    scanf ("%d", &A); /* Leitura do número */
    scanf ("%d", &B); /* Leitura da quantidade de vezes */
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= B; i++){
            
            printf ("\n%d", A);
            A++;
        }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

**Observação: Está não é a melhor e mais correta forma de se fazer um incremento, mas é um exemplo bem simples para entendimento**

2. **Decrementar**

É a mesma situação do incremento, só ocorre a mudança que ao invés de incrementarmos um número com *+1*, decrementamos com *-1*

Exemplificando com um algoritmo bem simples, em que um usuário *"X"* decide o número que será decrementado, e quantas vezes o mesmo será decrementado:

```c
int main(){
    
    int A; /* A vai ser o número que será decrementado*/
    int B; /* B vai ser quantas vezes esse número que será decrementado*/
    
    scanf ("%d", &A); /* Leitura do número */
    scanf ("%d", &B); /* Leitura da quantidade de vezes */
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= B; i++){
            
            printf ("\n%d", A);
            A--;
        }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

**Observação: Note que só foi necessário mudar o `A++` para `A--`**

Answer (score 1):

> O ato de incrementar é: adicionar mais um valor ao valor inicial, sendo assim o valor final vai ter um valor a mais.

```
// A variavel valor é definida com 1.
var valor = 1;

// A variável valor é "incrementada" e passa a ter 2.
// valor = valor + 1;
valor++;
```